# Объясните, как работает этот код?

Tags: javascript

Прохожу тему по рекурсии, и вот пример с code camp, который я никак не могу понять. Я понял что такое рекурсия, но можете расписать, в чем суть этого блока? Особенно после else. Как функция умножается на элемент массива?

```
  function multiply(arr, n) {
    if (n <= 0) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return multiply(arr, n - 1) * arr[n - 1];
    }
  }
```

Comment: `Как функция умножается на элемент массива?`  - Умножается результат функции, число.

Comment: возьмите в руки отладчик и отдебажьте код